# Can't close a Popup after clicking from a user control

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a user control (AddNewTransaction) inside a Popup (NewTransaction in DebtPage.xaml) that I open with this code:

[DebtPage.xaml.cs]

```
   public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!NewTransaction.IsOpen) { NewTransaction.IsOpen = true; }

                NewTransaction.HorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width) / 2 - (New_Transaction_Grid.Width / 2);
                NewTransaction.VerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height) / 2 - (New_Transaction_Grid.Height / 2);

                NewTransaction.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                RetanguloBranco_Background.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
```

The Popup opens and there's a custom control (AddNewTransaction) with a "Save" button. The button suppose to save data AND close the Popup. But it just save, the Popup keeps opened.

[AddNewTransaction.xaml.cs]

```
private static DebtPage _debtPage;
public static DebtPage debtPage
{
    get
    {
        if (_debtPage == null)
        {
            _debtPage = new DebtPage();
        }
        return _debtPage;
    }
}


private void BotaoSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SalvarTransaction(); //It's working!
    debtPage.ClosePopup_NewTransaction(); //It is not!
}
```

[DebtPage.xaml.cs]

```
public void ClosePopup_NewTransaction()
        {
            NewTransaction.IsOpen = false;

            NewTransaction.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            RetanguloBranco_Background.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with this:

```
private void BotaoSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SalvarTransaction();

            Grid gridParent = this.Parent as Grid;

            Popup parent = gridParent.Parent as Popup;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                parent.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
```

But I still want to know why `ClosePopup_NewTransaction();` does nothing.